# Crystal Report Duplicating fields

Tags: crystal-reports

hello im freasher in Crystal Report,  Im facing one problem that ,  I have two tables with data in ms access 
1.employee 2.Purachse order
two employees are there
purchase order comes in three types A,B and C
so i need to see the count of A,B,and c for each employees.
lets say
EMP POcount type
Abi         2          A
            1          B
       0       C
Bibi   5       A
       0       B
       1        C
Like this how could i do this

Answer (score 0):

```
    {@Count} // Place the formula the group header and hide it
    global numbervar code = 0;

    {@IncrementBarCount} // Place it in group body and hide it
    global numbervar code;
    if <DATABASE_COLUMN> = "A" then code := code + 1

    {@BarCount} // Place it where you want to see your result
    global numbervar code;
```